# ALSA stopped working with default device

Tags: linux, audio, kde

I had working sound on my Linux with 3 sound cards.
I had some old Sound Blaster which was working, an on-board sound card which a few months ago was not supported (so I turned it off in BIOS) and Nvidia/HDMI.

Today I discovered that my on-board card is finally supported, so I turned it on in BIOS and switched to it with speakers (so far OK - sound works)

Then I've removed this old sound blaster and I've no sound (at least not in a convenient way ;) ).

So now my `aplay -L` looks like (seems to be quite OK):

```
$ aplay -L
    null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
default:CARD=PCH
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Analog
    Default Audio Device
sysdefault:CARD=PCH
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Analog
    Front speakers
surround21:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Analog
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Digital
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=1
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 1
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=2
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 2
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 3
    HDMI Audio Output
```

also this is OK:

```
$ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7210000 irq 48
 1 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0xf7080000 irq 17
```

So my on-board card (`HDA Intel PCH`) is first one and is marked as default. That's what I want.

In KDE's control panel also `HDA Intel PCH` is on top just after first device called "default".

However if I try to test device "default" in KDE's control panel I've no sound.
In SMPlayer if I choose audio output driver to "alsa" (which I always used) also I've no sound. No sound in any other program (all were working).

But if I test in KDE's control panel `HDA Intel PCH` - it plays sound.
Also if I switch SMPlayer to next driver: `alsa (0,0 - HDA Intel PCH)` it plays.

So I have a simple conclusion here: ALSA's default device (or maybe it is some KDE's phonon problem?) doesn't actually point to HDA Intel PCH.
Maybe, before physical removal of Sound Blaster I should have erase it somehow from configurations?

My system is Arch x86_64.
I didn't mess up with any configuration files related to sound.

Answer (score 0):

It was my stupid oversight.
I assumed, that everything is correct with volume levels (at it was when I turned on the on board card) but it was bad assumption.

So I corrected it with alsamixer and now everything is fine.